# Least advantageous sport for individuals with super strength?

Tags: super-powers, sports, strength

The super strong individuals are approximately five times as strong as regular humans. Due to this, they are able to move their limbs much faster. They cannot think or react any faster than regular humans, however. Their fine motor skill is equivalent to regular humans. Their physical resilience is also extremely high compared to regular humans

What sports would individuals with super strength and other related powers have the least advantage over regular humans?

Comment: Ping Pong, Shooting, Pool (Billiards), Darts?

Comment: Chess, fencing (especially foil), croquet, curling, golf, skeleton sleighing, target shooting, and of course all motor sports? There are very many sports where brute strength is of little to no importance.

Comment: Curling.  if that’s even a sport.

Comment: formula 1 car racing... there's over 9000 such sports!

Comment: @AlexP Also horse racing, because of the same reason as motor sports.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it violates the [help/dont-ask], which requires questions to be specific, objectiely answered, and have a hope of one best answer. By definition, all answers to this question have equal value (prohibited). You know we don't like brainstorming questions, Ichty. Any sport will work so long as supers can only compete against other supers.

Comment: Stronger **does not** necessarily mean faster, it *just* means stronger.  You could make a human as strong as a much larger gorilla, but they would actually be *much* slower.  There are tradeoffs that you haven't considered... unless you're saying that these super-powers make muscles both stronger *and* faster, in which case there are still *other* tradeoffs.  Please edit your question to provide more details.

Comment: @JBH *By definition, all answers to this question have equal value* ...Are you honestly trying to tell me that weightlifting and go-karting will be equally fair for super-strong individuals to participate in?

Comment: @IchthysKing Go karting isn't a sport. A recreation, but not a sport... and you've missed the point. Every strength-based and/or agility-based sport can be manipulated to answer your question (even go karts, now that I think about it, agility...). Thus, every rational answer has equal value and you've violated SE's prohibition. You've asked here long enough to know that questions using superlatives (most, least, best, worst...) are almost always closed because such a question can only be answered based on the circumstances of your story. You also know better than to brainstorm.

Comment: @JBH The fact that it's possible to twist and manipulate an obviously incorrect answer to seem correct does not transform a good question into brainstorming. If you disagree, you've got about 28 thousand other 'brainstorms' to go handle

Comment: Ichti, this was closed for several reasons. I politely took the time to explain why I cast my vote. Honestly, I don't care if you like my reason or not, but it is frustrating that after so much time you're still trying to ignore the rules. HOWEVER, we've started the process of revamping the [help] including policies. [You're welcome to participate](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10334/40609) and, yes, we're expecting things to change. Many people would like to see a more story-based site, we just need to work out how.

Answer (score 4):

Competitive ballroom dancing. Your speed literally means nothing if your partner can't keep up, and even if they could, you wouldn't be in time with the song.

And there's only one situtation where your super strength might matter...I think I heard that there were Cha cha moves where the guy passes the girl around his back, but I don't know if that was a figure of speech or not. But even if true, it would be incredibly minor.

Comment: Without any doubt, the dance demands beauty and art, not strength or speed.

Answer (score 2):

## Archery

You do need some strength to be able to draw properly. But with all the leverage and gimmicks from modern compound bows - specially those gadgets used in the olympics - having that extra strength brings no advantages.

## American heritage sports

[From Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISSF_shooting_events)

> The International Shooting Sport Federation recognizes several shooting events, some of which have Olympic status.

Since it's a piece of machinery that is accelerating the projectile for you, having too much extra strentgh does not grant significant advantage. These sports favour freedom and hating the metric system over raw muscle.

Comment: Wish I could upvote this twice, just for the "hating the metric system" line.  I can handle draw weights for bows being in pounds, but using grains as the unit of weight in both archery and reloading is still frustrating me after decades.

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 the average height of a human male is 180 bullets

Answer (score -1):

League of legends or Counterstrike Esports....

or chess

or Tai Chi because you get arrested by the CCP if you actually defeat your grandmasters

or Hema... cause it's super easy killing a nerd dressed as a knight if you have **average** strength, let alone "super strength" and murder can be illegal sometimes.

Answer (score -1):

**Running**.

The frequency of the legs moving is bound to the frequency of the free swing of the leg, bent in the knee and the ankle as for running. So, even the great change of strength ( for example, your five times) raises the speed very slightly - (tenths of a percent). And if your supermen have larger muscles, their running speed will drop.

Notice, that the best runners are very far from being strong.

**Sailing on all yachts or windsurfing**. Here the strength won't help

**Chess and checkers**. :-)
Those belong to sports, too.

**Cricket and all sports that need accuracy** - more strength leads to less accuracy.

**Horse sports**
The personal strength of a jockey gives nothing. And if he has larger muscles, he loses.

**Acrobatics** and things. Tens of sports that demand beauty of movement.

All **air sports** without "the human-powered aircraft"

**Kite sports**

**Unicycle sports** - they demand equilibrium, not strength.

Really, simply look into [the list of sports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sports) - more than half of them do not demand strength.